# IIS Timeout whilst debugging on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis

I'm getting a frustrating error when debugging in Visual Studio 2010.

I'm fairly certain that its something to do with a setting on IIS but no idea what it is!

here is the error:-
'The Web server process that was being debugged has been terminated by IIS.'

The time-out happens every time I debug, on any of the various workspaces we have at work

takes about 90 seconds of inactivity on the debugger for the error to show

Comment: A bit more detail would be helpful.  Does the timeout happen regularly?  How long does it take before the timeout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IVE FOUND THE SOLUTION

In the advanced application pool settings in IIS you can change the maximum ping response time on the process model to stop the debugger timing out.